# Is there a way of running your code on a completely black monitor? (for text adventure)

Tags: python

I'm creating a text adventure game in python 3, and I was hoping to have the user interact with the game on a completely black monitor/screen. Is there any module/s etc. that could achieve this?

I've looked into pygame, and it seems like it can only run with the window edge (don't know what else to call it) present.

Comment: You should be able to switch to full screen mode in pygame

Comment: @kezper I think you're referring to the fullscreen vs windowed mode?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using pygame you can set it to either run full screen:

```
pygame.display.set_mode((0, 0), pygame.FULLSCREEN)
```

Or to run in windowed mode but without the window frame:

```
pygame.display.set_mode((100, 100), pygame.NOFRAME)
```

You can read more about it in their docs for [set_mode](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.set_mode)